# How to make a job run on all the servers in Ansible tower cluster?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

We have a clustered Ansible tower setup comprising of 3 servers. I want to run a patching job on all the 3 servers at a time it only runs on one server(which tower figures out based on internal algo). How do I make it run on 3 servers in cluster at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to a "Sliced Job" (or a "Distributed Job"):
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.6.2/html/installandreference/glossary.html#term-distributed-job

The Ansible Tower documentation goes over "Job Slicing" in section 17 (for Tower version 3.6.2):
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_slices.html

Please note this warning if you are trying to orchestrate a complex set of tasks across all the hosts:

```
Any job that intends to orchestrate across hosts
(rather than just applying changes to individual
hosts) should not be configured as a slice job. 
Any job that does, may fail, and Tower will not
attempt to discover or account for playbooks that
fail when run as slice jobs.
```

Job slicing is useful when you have to re-configure a lot of machines and want to use all of your Tower cluster capacity.  Using it for patching 100's of machines would be a good example, the only limits would be to ensure the source of the patches (the local patch server, or your Internet connect) have sufficient capacity to handle the load, and that any reboots of the systems are co-ordinated correctly in spite of the job slicing.

Comment: thanks for the response, I read about slicing and it definitely cleared up my misconceptions and confusions. Just to add, Input inventory is also important in order to use job slicing as it helps in distributing the inventory across the cluster,