# Ansible AWX: Behavior of Job Slicing

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I am running task against 3 servers and I have set job slicing option as 3.

After execution is completed I see below behavior

```
Job 1 : task executed for host-A
Job 2 - task executed for host-B and host-C
Job 3 - no hosts matched.
```

My understanding is Job 3 should have executed task for host-C or host-B. Is there any specific reason for this behavior?

I tried to set job slicing = 4 but still Job 3 & Job 4 results in no hosts matched.

Comment: I understand in your question that you are interested in "If Job Slicing is configured, How become the slices calculated for a different amount of jobs and hosts?". Even if it will not answer that question, does give [How to make a job run on all the servers in Ansible tower cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142349/6771046) more insight?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> *My understanding is Job 3 should have executed task for host-C or host-B.*

According the documentation [Job Slicing - Considerations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_slices.html#job-slice-considerations) that seems to be not the case

> *... a sliced job splits each inventory into a number of “slice size” chunks. It then queues jobs of ansible-playbook runs on each chunk of the appropriate inventory. The inventory fed into ansible-playbook is a pared-down version of the original inventory that only contains the hosts in that particular slice.*

Usually a/one job will become executed on/from a single node in your Ansible Tower cluster. Job Slicing is meant for distributing a/one job over multiple Ansible Tower Nodes.

> *... sliced jobs follow normal scheduling behavior (number of forks, queuing due to capacity, assignation to instance groups based on inventory mapping)*

If you have ~90 nodes in your inventory and configure 3 slices, than a workflow with 3 jobs each containing 30 nodes will be created and become executed in parallel. Even in your example you will need at least 3 Ansible Tower Nodes (maybe there are only 2?).

**Further Documentation**

- [Job slice execution behavior](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_slices.html#job-slice-execution-behavior)
- [Ansible Issue #7645 - "*Job Slice Calculation for Clustered Environments*"](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/7645)
- [Clustering](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/clustering.html)
- [Execution Environments](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/external_execution_envs.html)
- [Instance Groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/instance_groups.html)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and good explanation. I am actually looking for option where my playbook can be executed simultaneously on all nodes.

Comment: Regarding "_... looking for option where my playbook can be executed simultaneously on all nodes._" you may file a new question with a lot of more information and description, especially what you try to achieve.